# Update the example of the 2 Minute Tour

Tags: discussion

At the moment the [tour](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tour) refers to an example of the thread "[Does hot water freeze faster than cold water?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3371/does-hot-water-freeze-faster-than-cold-water)"

The problem is that the thread wouldn't be allowed by today's standards. The question contains no notable claim for which it provides citations.

I would also prefer if the tour would speak explicitly about the need for citations.

Answer (score 2):

I changed it for now to the Sharks and undersea cable question, that seemed to be the most appropriate from the first page of possible choices. If anyone has a better idea we can of course change this again.

Comment: @LangLangC If I remember correctly, we asked SE to flip a switch that reduces the strict eligibility criteria, as we had not a single allowed question. You'll have to do the same thing on Health.

Answer (score 0):

Questions don't require citations. The notable claim is that hot water freezes faster than cold water.

The second half of the question (practical applications) is off-topic though, so it is still not a great example question.

Comment: Notability is not established in the question by citing a public claim that hot water freezes faster than cold water. Today linking to an external claim is required. In '11 when the question was created it wasn't.

Comment: No, linking an external claim is not required. It has never been. The notability standard is only whether a bunch of adults believe the claim is true.

Comment: @Christian Articuno is unquestionably right here about notability. It's been asked before and is even in the FAQ. Links are not required. http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2497/must-every-questioned-notable-claim-include-a-referenced-citation-with-a-quote?rq=1